# Computer rebooting itself

Tags: windows-8.1

I have a Dell laptop (Inspiron 15 7000 series) that reboots itself whenever I lock the computer and walk away for a few minutes.

If I leave myself logged in I can come back hours later and everything's fine.

I've done some googing, and checked for crash memory dumps but don't have any clues at the moment for what's going on.

Comment: Have you watched it while it is locked to see if it gives any clues?

Comment: Have you checked the event log for any clues?

Comment: @AndrewMorton It looks like it will sit on the lock screen for a few minutes then the screen goes black.

Comment: @JulianKnight Nothing in the event log about unexpected shutdowns or anything similar. Just services starting back up.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Do you know if running the trace command triggers a reboot? Or if that will just wait until the next time a reboot occures

Comment: @AndrewWalters Ah, it's so long since I used it I'd forgotten about that. In the comments at [Diagnose Shutdown Problems with Xbootmgr](http://windowsitpro.com/systems-management/diagnose-shutdown-problems-xbootmgr), zshreez suggests an alternative.

Comment: @Andrew Morton Do you know if the diagnostics-performance tool got renamed? I don't see it in the control panel (Windows 8.1)

Comment: @AndrewWalters It's a hidden control panel item. In the control panel search box, start typing "reliability" - it's the "Action Center" -> "View reliability history" item.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Awesome, I see an unexpected crash listed on the 12th. That's probably about right, I'll try to cause some more crashes and see if they end up in the reliability monitor area

Comment: I've triggered some crashes from locking the computer today. Unfortunately there isn't any info in the control panel's reliability history. Any other things I could check?